# SQL Update and exists

Tags: sql-server

I have this query that checks if some id's exists in a table it modifies the value of another column.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT A.id,description,ab FROM tbl_C C
  JOIN tbl_B B ON ba=C.id
  JOIN tbl_A A ON A.id=B.value
  WHERE a=3)
    BEGIN UPDATE tbl_A
  SET ab=1
  where ab=0
  END
  ELSE 
   PRINT N'No values'
```

What happens here is that it modifies all the values, not only the ones in the IF EXISTS condition. How can I update only the ones that are selected in the IF EXISTS condition?

Comment: Use Joins in the UPDATE query

Comment: @PareshJ JOINS between what? the isServiceManual column has nothing to do with Async table, it is from Up table. Or maybe I don't understand what are you trying to say .

Comment: @PareshJ yes, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JOIN clause in UPDATE statement it makes it very easy to update data in one table from another table. Check this query and hope it helps you.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT A.id, descr, ab FROM tbl_C C
        JOIN BAsyncP ON a=C.id
        JOIN tbl_A Up ON A.id=B.value
        WHERE type=3)
    BEGIN 
        UPDATE Up
        SET A.ab=1
        FROM tbl_C C
            JOIN tbl_C ON ab=C.id
            JOIN tbl_A Up ON A.id=B.value
        WHERE type=3 AND A.ab=0
    END
ELSE 
    PRINT N'No values'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT Up.id,descr,isServiceManual FROM tbl_odw_asyncmessage  Async
JOIN tbl_ODW_AsyncMessageParam AsyncP  ON asyncMessageId=Async.id
JOIN tbl_ODW_UnloadingPoint Up  ON up.id=AsyncP.value
WHERE type=3)
 BEGIN UPDATE tbl_ODW_UnloadingPoint
SET isServiceManual=1
where isServiceManual=0 AND Up.id = Up.id
END
ELSE 
PRINT N'No values'
```

maybe this helps??

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT A.id,descr,ab FROM tbl_C C
  JOIN tbl_B B  ON ba=C.id
  JOIN tbl_A A ON up.id=B.value
  WHERE type=3)

BEGIN UPDATE up 
   SET A.ab=1
   FROM tbl_C C
   JOIN tbl_B BON ba=Async.id
   JOIN tbl_A A ON up.id=B.value
   WHERE type=3
   and 
   A.ab=0

 END
 ELSE 
 PRINT N'No values'
```

Answer (score 0):

Let try below code.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT Up.id,descr,isServiceManual FROM tbl_odw_asyncmessage Async
  JOIN tbl_ODW_AsyncMessageParam AsyncP  ON asyncMessageId=Async.id
  JOIN tbl_ODW_UnloadingPoint Up  ON up.id=AsyncP.value
  WHERE type=3)
  Begin
      Update tbl_ODW_UnloadingPoint set isServiceManual=1
      where isServiceManual=0
      and 
      exists (
      SELECT Up.id FROM tbl_odw_asyncmessage Async
      JOIN tbl_ODW_AsyncMessageParam AsyncP  ON asyncMessageId=Async.id
      where tbl_ODW_UnloadingPoint.id = AsyncP.value
      and type=3
       )
    End
ELSE 
    PRINT N'No values'
```